# How do I strictly type ref argument of fowardRef() when forwarding multiple refs to polymorphic component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a unique problem.  I am creating a UI component in React with Typescript and I want developers to have a reference to the polymorphic child elements of the component.  I've created a simplified version of my component to show you my dilemma.

```js
type FancyInputProps<
  Container extends React.ElementType = 'div',
  FormElement extends React.ElementType = 'input',
  CallToAction extends React.ElementType = 'button'
> = {
  containerAs?: Container;
  formElementAs?: FormElement;
  callToActionAs?: CallToAction;
};

const FancyInput = React.forwardRef(
  <
    Container extends React.ElementType = 'div',
    FormElement extends React.ElementType = 'input',
    CallToAction extends React.ElementType = 'button'
  >(
    {
      containerAs,
      formElementAs,
      callToActionAs,
    }: FancyInputProps<Container, FormElement, CallToAction>,
    ref?: React.Ref<unknown> //  I would like to make this strictly typed
  ) => {
    const ContainerComponent = containerAs || 'div';
    const FormElementComponent = formElementAs || 'input';
    const CallToActionComponent = callToActionAs || 'button';

    const containerRef = useRef(null);
    const formElementRef = useRef(null);
    const callToActionRef = useRef(null);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      get containerRef() {
        return containerRef.current;
      },
      get formElementRef() {
        return formElementRef.current;
      },
      get callToActionRef() {
        return callToActionRef.current;
      },
    }));

    return (
      <ContainerComponent ref={containerRef}>
        <FormElementComponent ref={formElementRef} />
        <CallToActionComponent ref={callToActionRef} />
      </ContainerComponent>
    );
  }
);

FancyInput.displayName = 'FancyInput';
```

This component above works as expected. However, I have no idea how to strictly type the `ref` argument for `React.forwardRef()` when using `useImperitiveHandle()` along with polymorphic components.

For example, when I use my component, I get an error that `Property 'callToActionRef' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)`

What type should I use to replace `React.Ref<unknown>`?

```js
const UsageDemo = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref?.current?.callToActionRef.focus() //  this line has the type error
  })

  return <FancyInput ref={ref} callToActionAs="a" />;
};
```

You can test the code yourself here...
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-snow-wn6hg3?file=/src/index.tsx